# I am getting error in my MYSQL stored procedure with input parameter in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am trying to execute the following MYSQL stored procedure in SQL window in phpmyadmin:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE searchtoy (IN toy_no INT)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM Toy
WHERE Toy_ID = toy_no;
END;
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Where is the mistake I am making ?
It would be really helpful if the solution code is provided to fix this error.

Comment: How did you create the procedure? Did you write the entire code by hands or have you used procedure manager inside phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes, I typed it manually in a SQL window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the delimiter to // or something else and it will work fine the code stops compiling after getting confused over the ; of select as the delimiter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVBuN.png)

Comment: I have added // in Delimiter text box and it worked.